# Custom Matching with Moq

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, moq

I am attempting to be a good TDD citizen as I design an application.  I'm using Moq, and I've run into a little repository issue.

My repository has a Find method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where(where);
        }
```

Then I attempt to set up a mock of the repository:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Find(c => c.ConferenceID == conferenceID))
                .Returns(ConferenceTestObjectContainer.CreateConferences().Where(c => c.ConferenceID == conferenceID).ToList());
```

The test will work if I test against the mock directly in the test, but if I inject the mock into my production code (an ASP.NET page in this case,) and test the page method, it doesn't work.

Justin Etheredge addresses the problem in his post [here](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2009/08/19/Comparing-Simple-Lambda-Expressions-With-Moq.aspx).  The issue is that the comparer between the call and the setup can't handle Expressions so well.

The problem that I'm having is with his comparer function:

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> AreEqual<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expr)
{
    return Match<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>
        .Create(t => t.ToString() == expr.ToString());            
}
```

This raises a compiler error:

***The type arguments for method 'Moq.Match.Create(System.Predicate)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.***

I understand that the compiler can't infer the type of "T", but I'm not clear on how to fix that.  The good Mr. Etheredge made this work, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this question is going Tumblweed...

For the record, I worked around the problem by deriving a new Entity-specific Repository and added a FindById() method, which works great.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use somenthing like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> AreEqual<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expr)
{
    return Match.Create<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>(t => t.ToString() == expr.ToString());            
}
```

In this way I'm handling generic as well.